# How to repair permissions on /usr/local after accidentally changed?

Tags: permission

I accidentally run command `chown -R paulie /usr/local` (I needed to add some subfolders).

How can I get it back?

Now I already resolved problem with mysql data, but still have problems with gcc, for example.

Comment: /usr/local is all under your control so no defined way

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only changed the owner (as your command states), you can return everything back to root ownership by

```
chown -R root /usr/local
```

If you think you may need to fix the group ownership too, then this is better

```
chown -R root:wheel /usr/local
```

Comment: yes, it is the only problem. But I am sure, root ownership for all is not the right solution. For example /usr/local/data/mysql should be owned by _mysql user.

Comment: I see...  My mysql is buried in /opt/ and all of the files in my /usr/local/ are owned by root; but, it depends on what other software you've installed, and how it was installed, etc.  Short of restoring from backup, or browsing the backup to see what is not owned by root, there is no simple way to do that.